# pymssql executemany insert valueerror

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql, executemany

I get an error:

> File "pymssql.pyx", line 443, in pymssql.Cursor.executemany
>   (pymssql.c:6616)   File "pymssql.pyx", line 417, in
>   pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:6057)   File "_mssql.pyx", line 943,
>   in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:9858)   File
>   "_mssql.pyx", line 974, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
>   (_mssql.c:9734)   File "_mssql.pyx", line 1091, in
>   _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query (_mssql.c:10814)   File "_mssql.pyx", line 1113, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command
>   (_mssql.c:11042)   File "_mssql.pyx", line 1797, in
>   _mssql._substitute_params (_mssql.c:18646) ValueError: more placeholders in sql than params available

while executing bulk insert into mssql table (executemany). Inserting the same data in one execute statemend as well as in mssql management studio works just fine.

I tried executemany (data) with dictionary and a tuple - same result.

The code:

```
cursor.executemany("insert table Values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", (data))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post results of `print(len(data))` and `print(set(map(len, data)))`?

Comment: len(data)==602
set(map(len,data)==set([11,12,13,15,16,17,18,19,20,21])

Comment: right, I should have thought about that. Solved, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sublists/subtuples in `data` should have length 21 (the number of %s in your SQL query).

But. Your `data` have also items with length 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, and 20.
And you get the error `more placeholders (meaning: %s) in sql than params (meaning: sublists in data) available`

To fix: check how you're generating `data` and mercilessly twenty-one every `data` item.